# Flutter App Deployment fails due to signing of Frameworks

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode, deployment

When building the `ipa` package of my Flutter app for a production (no simulator) target, everythin runs smoothly. But, whenever I try to deploy the package to AppStoreConnect, no matter if via XCode itself or via the Transporter App, I'm getting the following error below, and the same error for every single Flutter package that my application uses:

> Asset validation failed (90035)
> Invalid Signature. Code failed to satisfy specified code requirement(s). The file at path “Runner.app/Frameworks/FBLPromises.framework/FBLPromises” is not properly signed. Make sure you have signed your application with a distribution certificate, not an ad hoc certificate or a development certificate. Verify that the code signing settings in Xcode are correct at the target level (which override any values at the project level). Additionally, make sure the bundle you are uploading was built using a Release target in Xcode, not a Simulator target. If you are certain your code signing settings are correct, choose “Clean All” in Xcode, delete the “build” directory in the Finder, and rebuild your release target. For more information, please consult https://developer.apple.com/support/code-signing

So regarding the recommendations:

> Make sure you have signed your application with a distribution certificate, not an ad hoc certificate or a development certificate.

-> I actually don't understand how to control that. Do I have to specifically create a distribution certificate? In XCode, while under Runner > Signing & Capabilities, the Team that I've selected is simply the one of my individual developer account, for which it says `1 certificate included: Apple Development`. So is the problem that I'm using a development and not a distribution certificate?

> Verify that the code signing settings in Xcode are correct at the target level (which override any values at the project level).

-> Checked, they're the same

> Additionally, make sure the bundle you are uploading was built using a Release target in Xcode, not a Simulator target.

-> I'm using `any iOS Device (arm64)`, so this shouldn't be an issue.

> If you are certain your code signing settings are correct, choose “Clean All” in Xcode, delete the “build” directory in the Finder, and rebuild your release target.

-> Done, same outcome.

> For more information, please consult https://developer.apple.com/support/code-signing. (ID: fe5251bf-66f7-4d2f-a906-fabd58fe8529)

-> Searching and troubleshooting for hours, but nothing seemed to solve my problem.

I've noticed that within XCode, a warning proposes a change to perform saying `Target 'flutter_native_splash' - Disable Code Signing`, recommending me to disable the code signing for that framework, as it could be problematic. And it does so for all frameworks causing the deployment errors actually, and recommends to disable the code signing for them for all the Debug, Profile and Release configurations. Yet the official Apple Docs consider the code signing of the app's entire code as an important security feature, hence I do not really understand XCodes recommendation here. Is it general practice to disable code signing in Frameworks for app deployment? Or is the error somewhere on the Flutter-side?

Comment: "So is the problem that I'm using a development and not a distribution certificate?" Yes. You need to create a distribution certificate on the Apple developer account page.

Comment: Cheers, but I'm confused. I've created a Distribution certificate, but what do I have to do now to be able to use it within XCode? The docs available online do not really inform about this.. Is it possible to have a development and a distribution certificate for the same Signing Team? Because I do not understand how I can select the according Distribution key within XCode after adding it

Comment: You need to download it and install it into your keychain and then it should get selected automatically. Earlier when I said create the certificate via the Apple web page, actually you can do it within Xcode which probably will make things easier as Xcode will then download it and install it etc. Go to XCode|Settings|Account, select your Apple ID and team, then click Manage Certificates, that will bring up a dialog and in the bottom left hand corner is a + button, click on it and you can create a distribution certificate. I'd suggest you to read Apple's docs and tutorials on dist certs.

Comment: Thanks again! I've done all of this, but the dist cert is not showing up in XCode, not even after restarting it / generating a provisioning profile in my Developer Account that I relate with the dist cert which is also added into my keychain. Any idea why? Do I maybe have to add the Provisioning Profile to the Team selectable in XCode, or something like that? The docs don't inform about these things here, AFAI can tell.

Comment: I don't know if Xcode should the distribution certificate or not, it shows developer ones. Important thing is if its in the keychain

Comment: Thank you sir, all goody now, formulated an according answer below! Thanks really!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Pipeants, I was able to solve this, as it's imho not really clearly explained in Apple's Developer Docs:

1. Create a Distribution Certificate
2. Install the Distribution Certification within your machine's keychain
3. Generate a provisioning profile (of type `Distribution`) for the concerned App's APP ID in your Apple Developer Account.
4. Relate it with the generated Distribution Certificate within your Apple Developer Account
5. Install the Provisioning Profile on your local machine. This did absolutely nothing that can be visually seen on my mac, besides opening XCode. But apparently this did the trick.
6. Whenever you build your Flutter Release App, it will now automatically use your Distribution Certificate to sign everything, even if your XCode still lists `Apple Development` as the Type of the Signing Certificate used for your project. This is an assumption, as all of the listed steps eliminated all of the framework-signing related errors.